# Renormalization condition for field strength renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, greens-functions, propagator, self-energy

I am studying $\phi^4$ theory and so far I understand the mass and coupling constant renormalizations. In these theories, once we expand a diagram in perturbation theory we "cancel" the divergences by demanding the value we get from the diagram equals a measured quantity such as the physical mass or physical coupling.

For field strength renormalization I understand the need for it and how it appears, but because it is not physical like mass or the coupling constant are I am less sure about the corresponding renormalization condition. My guess is that if we define our physical field $\phi$ as $\phi = Z^{-1/2}\phi_0$ where $\phi_0$ is the bare field, then we require that in the UV limit the physical field has coefficient 1. This places a condition on $Z$ so that the physical fields have no dependence on the momentum cutoff.

Is this correct or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any loop level, the general form of the dressed propagator of the $\phi^4$ theory is
$$\tilde{D}_\text{resummed}(p)=\frac{i}{p^2-m_0^2(\Lambda)-\Sigma(p^2,\Lambda)}\tag{1}\label{1},$$
where $\Sigma$ is the self-energy, i.e. the sum of 1PI diagrams. Although at one-loop level the self energy depends merely on the cutoff scale $\Lambda$ displays no $p$ dependence, it does at higher loop levels. The effect is that not only the pole of the propagator is shifted - giving rise as OP knows to the renormalized mass in the [on shell renormalization scheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_renormalization_scheme), but it also changes the behaviour around the pole, i.e. the residue. In fact, if you define $m_R$, the renormalized mass by
$$p^2-m_0^2(\Lambda)-\Sigma(p^2,\Lambda)\lvert_{p^2=m_R}=0$$
The expansion of the propagator around the pole yields
$$\frac{i}{p^2-m_0^2(\Lambda)-\Sigma(p^2,\Lambda)}\tag{2}\label{2}\approx\frac{iZ}{p^2-m_R}+\text{(finite terms)},$$
where
$$Z=1-\frac{d\Sigma}{dp^2}\bigg\lvert_{p^2=m_R}\tag{3}\label{3}$$. As a side note, OP may have recognized that \eqref{2} is the [Källén-Lehmann spectral representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4ll%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lehmann_spectral_representation) of the propagator. Rescaling the fields as OP mentions removes $Z$ from the numerator of \eqref{2}.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.